# $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0$ $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n-c_n)=0$ imply $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+c_n)=0$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits

Consider some sequence $\{a_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}<0$, $\{b_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}>0$, $\{c_n\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}>0$  and assume
$$
\begin{cases}
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0\\
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n-c_n)=0
\end{cases}
$$
Does this imply
$$
\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+c_n)=0 \text{ ?}
$$

---

I am confused because:
$$
\begin{cases}
(1) \hspace{1cm}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+b_n)=0 \text{ is equivalent to write } a_n=-b_n+o(1)\\
(2) \hspace{1cm}\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (b_n-c_n)=0\text{ is equivalent to write } b_n=c_n+o(1)\\
\end{cases}
$$
Put (2) in (1) and get
$$
a_n=-c_n+o(1)+o(1)=-c_n+o(1) \text{ which is equivalent to write } \lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (a_n+c_n)=0\\
$$
where $o(1)$ is a number converging to zero as $n\rightarrow \infty$

What is wrong in my arguments?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. First, assume $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + c_n) = x$ where $x \ne 0$. Now add the second equation to get
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + c_n) + \lim_{n\to\infty} (b_n - c_n) = x + 0$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n + c_n - c_n) = x$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) = x$$
Since we already know from the equations given that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + b_n) = 0$, this leads to a contradiction proving that $x = 0$ and thus that $\lim_{n\to\infty} (a_n + c_n) = 0$.

Comment: The contradiction implies either $x=0$ or $x$ does not exist. Why have you assumed $x=0$ is the true branch, doesn't that need to be proven that the limit indeed exists?

Answer (score 2):

No.

You could have $a_n=-n$, $b_n=c_n=n$.

Comment: Thanks, could you briefly explain why my arguments above are wrong? (see added part)

Comment: Am I missing something here? Don't these values satisfy all 3 equations

Comment: I do not believe this answer applies any longer.

Comment: This answer is wrong